What needs to be done when migrating a Craft site to a new server?
My hosting provider moved my Craft 2.9.2 site to a new server.  The entire virtual server was moved to a new site, so in theory nothing should have changed but the IP address.  DNS records have been updated.  However, users can no longer log into the site, and the behavior is very inconsistent.  Some people can't even get to the login page, some can but can't log in (browser just returns an empty page), some can reach the login page in Chrome but not Firefox.
The only thing that works is the admin panel.  The only relevant log message since the migration is "Tried to restore session from a cookie, but the given hashed database token value does not appear to belong to the given login name."
When Craft is migrated, what steps need to be taken so that everything works?
